# Why not rebuild the flutter widgets every one second instead of using complex state managers?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, simplify, flutter-hive

I've found a very naive and easy approach for state management in flutter. I am storing the state using a hive box (a key value database) and rebuilding the screen at every second with setState.

The widget is not accessing an API. Just the hive database that is very fast and light weigh.

I guess that it is wrong but what is the problem with that approach in practice? Will that use lots of battery, too much CPU, cause crashes, memory leak? I don't think so.

Please, give a good reason not to do it.

```
late Box db;

main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  db = await Hive.openBox('db');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 @override
 void initState() {
   Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => setState(() {}));
   super.initState();
 }
 
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   double someValue = db.get('someValue', defaultValue: 0.0);

   // Show someValue in a Text
 }
```

Comment: If the user doesn't interact there will be no changes on state, it will consume the resources & every second is not enough, perhaps  providing  60 fps to draw, means for single part to change update them all .

Comment: For my silly app one second is enough. It is not a game, it is just a form. For sure it will use unnecessary resources. Just don´t know how relevant these resources are. Maybe it is nothing to affect the device battery or CPU.

Comment: I will use listener  instead of timer while it is a form

Comment: why get a haircut every time it grows when you can just cut it every 1 hour for no need, I hope it got you the idea.

Comment: another cause to not do it, is an application that has a lot of themes, while you can change the state of the whole app when the user wants to change it, you want to change on periodic times while there is no need, this will cause lagging in the app for sure, which the user will interact with and think it's a trash app, please just try yo see the difference in the flutter dev tools in profile me.

Comment: I guess it is a great strategy for prototyping. If the app goes into production you can always change it later. I will come back later to give feedback on how that experiment ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to flutter the question is seen as very logical and makes sense for the new developer so the sweet and simple answer is yes you can do this. But it's totally against the software development ethics and can make your app much slower than the average flutter app. The main concern during the development of any software especially a mobile app is that you have to think about the lower-end device that does not have good battery life and enough memory to run the most optimized application.

**Conclusion**

in some cases, you can use this method to periodically rebuild your flutter widget but always remember it will increase the chance of an unexpected crash and definitely will cause some UI lagging issues. In short, **the main responsibility of the State manager is not to rebuild the widget tree but to avoid that unnecessary build.**
for more insight, you can review your app performance with flutter [Dart DevTools](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools#:%7E:text=Dart%20DevTools%20is%20a%20suite,Flutter%20web)